Unexplained Memory Spikes with Dockerized Go Application and PostgreSQL/Redis Setup
I'm not sure if this is a ServerFault issue, but I will try to post this here first, as my software is programmed with go.
So have I Ubuntu 22.04, running the following:

docker and docker-compose
Inside a container, My golang compiled Software
Inside a container, postgreSQL
Inside a container, redis
Inside a container, a mosquitto broker
Inside one last small container, out of docker-compose, is running node-exporter for prometheus and the charts you're seeing here below. Data is reported every 15s.

The host is running on a Google Cloud VM with 6cpu and 40GB of ram.
My golang software is in charge of handling data coming from hundreds of thousands IOT devices in real-time.
From now on, please keep in mind, whenever I'm talking about my server being idle, I actually mean my server is still receiving data, handling it, pushing logs to an external database, and updating redis/postgres data linked to my devices.
Here's what's happening in an idle scenario:
Memory: idle memory - That's a lot of ram being used in the heap, and it is so by design.
Cpu: idle cpu - The CPU usage fluctuates, which I've found is due to the Go garbage collector running every two minutes. It’s not optimal, but it’s necessary to manage the large heap, so overall, it’s manageable. There's also redis, snapshotting itself every now and then, and cpu spikes a little here because of non-stop reads and writes when this happens.
This setup isn’t performing too badly. I have other instances with less traffic that have been running for months without issues, so I’m confident there are minimal (if any) memory leaks in my software.
Finally: idle htop
All is good. Memory cache is not too high, the system is stable.
Until this happens:
Memory spike - Cpu not so bad spike
The entire host memory usage(not talking about cache..) more than doubles! These short-lived spikes are short in time-never over 2 minutes-, start up slow, and end up high, happen for no apparent reasons and can't be traced to any active process.
Here's an htop example of when this is happening, sorted by memory usage
It looks like no process is using that memory.
I also managed to profile the heap and the cpu (for 30 seconds) of my software when this happens with pprof. And... Nothing unusual.
I also created a script that checks the total memory of the system and whenever it's over 60% dump a lot on information using smem, top, pmap, zombie processes etc.. I also dump active queries when this happens and there's basically nothing there either... nothing reports high RSS memory usage. I'm willing to share the dumps if anyone thinks it could help finding the root cause of this.
/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory is 1, /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio is 50
Here's also free -m output when this happens:
Memory Usage Summary:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           40100       31644         291         146        8165        7804
Swap:              0           0           0
Detailed Memory Info:
MemTotal:       41063324 kB
MemFree:          297776 kB
MemAvailable:    7991456 kB
Buffers:           87280 kB
Cached:          7883384 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          6352984 kB
Inactive:       14573596 kB
Active(anon):    3089084 kB
Inactive(anon): 10003948 kB
Active(file):    3263900 kB
Inactive(file):  4569648 kB
Unevictable:       27620 kB
Mlocked:           27620 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:              1376 kB
Writeback:            48 kB
AnonPages:      12980008 kB
Mapped:           438904 kB
Shmem:            149864 kB
KReclaimable:     390732 kB
Slab:             495720 kB
SReclaimable:     390732 kB
SUnreclaim:       104988 kB
KernelStack:        7840 kB
PageTables:        38652 kB
SecPageTables:         0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    20531660 kB
Committed_AS:   15943372 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       16976 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             4800 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:      8192 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Unaccepted:            0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      105272 kB
DirectMap2M:     5134336 kB
DirectMap1G:    38797312 kB

I'm open to any kind of advice.
It has to be my software right? I don't want to blame redis or postgres, but this is starting to become frustrating and I'm at a loss about what to look for.
I'm starting to believe the database is the issue, but it looks like the issue appears 10-15 minutes AFTER running some not so heavy select queries. Which doesn't really make sense to me.
Any idea?
Thank you
Edit: on more piece of information. All containers are running without limits. Additionally, docker stats also reports everything is running with normal values when these spikes happen
